# how to combine to array for chartjs width php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

i need help how to make php code for array data to chartjs, i use 2 table and i hope to generate array code like below

```
function revenueCost(year) {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=\'csrf-token\']').attr('content')
        },
        url: url,
        data: {
            year: $('#year').val(),
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            $('#revenue-cost').empty();
            var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('revenue-cost'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: data.label,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Revenue',
                        data: data.revenue,
                        borderWidth: 0.5,
                        borderColor: '#00642c',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,100,44,0.2)'
                    },{
                        label: 'Cost',
                        data: data.cost,
                        borderWidth: 0.5,
                        borderColor: '#a80e19',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(168,14,25,0.2)'
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {beginAtZero: true}
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    });
}
```

and i want to make array like this

```
{"label":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"revenue":[105,85,55,68,72,8,0,0,0,0,0,0],"cost":[41,32,22,23,26,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

and chartjs view like this
[chartjs grouping month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ELsy.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I see the solution could be simple:

1. Send a POST HTTP request to your PHP file.
2. Validate you have a POST request with an if sentence and isset($_POST)
3. Prepare or extract the data, and create an associative array like the next one:

> ```
> $label_data = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
> $revenue_data = [105,85,55,68,72,8,0,0,0,0,0,0];
> $cost_data = [41,32,22,23,26,3,0,0,0,0,0,0];
>
> $data = [
>     'label'   => $label_data,
>     'revenue' => $revenue_data,
>     'cost'    => $cost_data
> ];
>
> echo json_encode($data);
> ```

if you have data divided between arrays just merge them with array_merge and store the result in a new variable

> ```
> $label_first = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"];
> $label_second = ["Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
> $label_data = array_merge($label_first, $label_second );
> ```

4. Finally catch the response in your $.ajax and, perform the action you want to do the data.

I hope this information could be useful for you.